# Django-.csv file is not properly storing

Tags: python, html, pandas, forms, file

**views.py**

```
def preprocessedDatafile(request):
    file2 = request.FILES["myfile"]
    dtf = pd.DataFrame(file2)
    dtf.to_csv(
        "E:/Preprocessed/preprocessed data.csv"
    )
    return render(request, "preprocessedDatafile.html")
```

In the above pd is the panadas library object.

**.html**

```
<form class="grid" method="POST" action="{% url 'preprocessedDatafile' %}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}    
                <div style="border: 1px dashed rgb(148,10,34); width:59%" >
                <br/><br/>
                <input type="file" class='upload-box' accept=".csv" name='myfile'/>
                <br/><br/><br/>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" id="btn" ><b>Submit</b></button>
            </form>
```

I am making a web page, where I have to read a csv file and then store this csv file in a specific location. What I want to do is done but the new csv that I am storing have some garbage data and all data is storing in one column. I want to store new file data same as the original file data. For more understanding the picture of original file is:
[image]

and the picture of new file that is currently storing is:
[image]

I hope you understood what I am taking. Is there a way to get the same data as in the original file in the new file that I am storing.

Comment: I've never worked with Django and i've never had to use files in my minimal web dev experience. But the "b" signifies the data is in bytes. 1) If you can i'd try this out with a .xlsx (excel) file and see if you have the same issue. 2) i'd look into if theres maybe some sort of compression happening in the file transfer?

Comment: actually, I am working on a project where I have to apply preprocessing on a csv file that is given by user in a web page. After that I have to use this csv file for applying machine learning algorithms on a web page. That's why I want to use csv file.

Answer (score 0):

I used the below code in the views.py file and my problem is resolved.

```html
def preprocessedDatafile(request):
    file2 = request.FILES["myfile"]
    dtfb = pd.read_csv(file2)
    dtf = pd.DataFrame(dtfb)
    dtf.to_csv(
        "E:/Preprocessed/preprocessed data.csv"
    )
    return render(request, "preprocessedDatafile.html")
```

Comment: Please only use the snippet feature for code that runs in the browser